# How can I make this construction simpler?

Tags: javascript, arrays

#### How can I make this construction simpler?

```
 categories.map(item => {
        localCategories.map(localItem => {
          if (localItem.id === item.id) {
            item.name = localItem.name;
          }
        });
      });
```

#### localCategories is an array of objects from json file..............

#### categories is a similar array..............

```
"localCategories": 
          [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "Музыка",
              "img" : "31526348973.png"
            },
            {
              "id": "4",
              "name": "Жңылык",
              "img" : "31526309377.png"
            },
            {
              "id": "7",
              "name": "Балдарга",
              "img": "31526300037.png"
            }
]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by simple?

Comment: Are you trying to merge two arrays into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `map` and `find`. Note that `findById` is [curried](http://2ality.com/2011/09/currying-vs-part-eval.html) for improved readability in the `find` method:

```
const findById = id => list => list.id === id

categories.map(category => ({
  ...category,
  name: localCategories.find(findById(category.id)).name,
}))
```

You might want to ensure that the found object exists by doing something like this inside the `map` so that an error isn't thrown when trying to access the `name` property:

```
const foundCategory = localCategories.find(findById(category.id))
return {
  ...category,
  name: foundCategory ? foundCategory.name : 'Some default value',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really "simpler" but easier to read:

```
localCategories.forEach(({name, id}) =>
  categories.find(c => c.id === id).name = name);
```

Or a probably daster way using lookup tables:

```
const catByID = new Map(localCategories.map(c => ([c.id, c]));

categories.forEach(({id, name}) => catById.get(id).name = name);
```